# Retrieve all the posts done through my facebook app in some specified time?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

I take `stream_publish` permission from user, and use it to publish some content to facebook wall.
In the insights page, I see number N wall posts done on specific date.
Is there any graph api call or FQL through which I can retrieve all the wallposts that were done using my app's application id and access_tokens on that specific date ?
or may be last 100 wallposts that were done through my app.

I do have `read_stream` permission for each user's access_token .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this graph call:

`fql?q=SELECT message, attachment, attribution, app_id from stream where source_id=me() and app_id={appId} LIMIT 100`